# Best method for Concatenating N strings of length L_N?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have N strings representing points in for of (x,y,z).
I'm trying to create one string with all of my points in the following form:
[(x_0,y_0,z_0),(x_1,y_1,z_1),...,(x_n,y_n,z_n)]

The following is the method I'm trying but If feel it gets overcomplex:

1. Calculate the beginning of the next point in the string.
2. Use sprintf(string + index, point_i);
3. Repeat for all points.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: A major issue you don't mention is how to allocate the character array for the string.

Comment: I calculate the total length of the future string and do the following:
char* newString = malloc(length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprintf` returns the number of characters 'printed' (added to the string), so you can start with an index of 0 and then simply add the result of each next `sprintf (string + index, ..`.

Comment: +1, of course checking for index limits (don't overrun the buffer) and valid return values (`res > -1`) for the `sprintf` result is *highly* recommended. See [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should achieve the desired string formatting:

```
char* pathAsString(int nPoints, point3d_t* points)
{
    int i, offset, buf_len;
    char* buf;

    buf_len = nPoints * 29 + 2;
    buf = malloc(buf_len);
    buf[0] = '[';
    offset = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
        n = snprintf(buf + offset, buf_len - offset, "(%8.3f,%8.3f,%8.3f),",
            points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
        if (n < buf_len - offset)
            return NULL; /* string buffer too small or other error */
        offset += n;
    }

    if (offset + 1 >= buf_len)
        return NULL; /* string buffer too small*/

    buf[offset] = ']';
    buf[offset+1] = 0;

    return buf;
}
```

It's basically the same approach that Jongware proposed as well. Instead of `sprintf`, it uses the safer `snprintf` to protect against buffer overruns.

Note that the calculation of the required string length isn't very robust. If one of the numbers doesn't fit into 8 characters (or whatever you choose), `snprintf` will uses more than the calculated number of characters and the buffer won't be sufficiently large. A better algorithm would probably dynamically size the array, especially if you use a number format with a dynamic length.